# Showing that $\frac{\mathbb{C}[X]}{<x-1>}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to show that $\frac{\mathbb{C}[X]}{<x-1>} \cong \mathbb{C}$ and I am not sure if this argument is correct.

Define $\phi: \mathbb{C}[X] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\sum a_it^i \to \sum a_i$. My aim is to show that $ker\phi = <x-1>$. Now we know by the first isomorphism theorem that the image of this map is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and hence it is an integral domain, and so $ker \phi$ must be prime, and as $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a P.I.D then $ker\phi$ must be generated by an irreducible polynomial. Now $(x-1)$ is an irreducible polynomial in the kernel, and so $ker\phi = <x-1>$

Does this argument work?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good !...

Comment: There's a little thing missing. If $\operatorname{im}\phi$ were $\{0\}$, then it wouldn't be an integral domain. Once you note $\operatorname{im}\phi \neq \{0\}$, it works.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  His argument makes me think he's working in the category of rings with identity, so $1 \in \mathrm{im}\phi$.  (This assumption is not stated, so I may be wrong.)

Comment: Ah yes, I was implicitly assuming that $R$ is a commutative ring with 1

Comment: @EricTowers Even so, one must note that $\phi$ is a (unital) ring homomorphism to use the theorems on kernels of ring homomorphisms.

Comment: The bit I was unsure of is just because $x-1$ is in the kernel and is irreducible, can we be sure that then $x-1$ must be the generator?

Comment: $x-1$ has degree one and is in a PID.  What is the degree of a supposed generator of the PID if that generator is not $x-1$?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand that comment, is there some direct argument to show that $x-1$ must be the generator? Why couldn't the kernel be $<x-2>$ for example?

Comment: Have you justified that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of rings? It is, but your teacher may want to check that you know why. Other than that it does look good to me.

Comment: I know how to check that so should be fine. To argue that $x-1$ is the generator, can we say that if $f$ is the generator then $f$ should divide $x-1$ but $x-1$ is irreducible so $f$ and $x-1$ are associates?